# Parse Input type number value to Integer from Double

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, jstl

I want to **parse** input type number value to input since its value is already coming from controller

```
<input type="number" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" value="${user.variant}" required>
```

I am ignoring the floating type value therefore `onkeypress` I am disabling decimal values or negative numbers.

The problem here is that if I am setting the decimal value in **value attribute** of the input tag then it should parse that double value to integer value.

**Hint:** something like: 
`value = "pattern(regex+${user.variant})"` or `value = "parseInt${user.variant}"`

I don't know whether above code is right or wrong its just that I didn't find anything yet on this.

Comment: So why are you not rounding it on the serverside?

Comment: Actually the thing is I am the service is giving the response in POJO class and even if I have to do this then I need to get the attribute then set again in that POJO class object again

Comment: been ages since I have jstl, but isn;t there fmt:formatNumber or something like that?

Comment: @epascarello Yes there is I am using it for uppercase somewhere in my code I will check if there is for parsing and let you know here

Comment: @epascarello sorry I was away for a while but I got the answer thanks....<fmt:parseNumber var="variantValue" integerOnly="true"  type="number" value="${user.variant}" />

<input type="number" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" value="<c:out value="${variantValue}"/>" required>

Comment: I want you to update the answer because you helped me I was not looking or thinking of jstl I was busy changing either the html input attribute or javascript or jquery code